# Json.dumps alternative in Redshift

Tags: sql, json, amazon-redshift, mysql-real-escape-string

I have strings like

```
Origi\"nal
```

and

```
Origi"nal
```

. I want to convert them to raw string and then to a Json String and write to a table in Redshift.

Example output of "select col from table"  should be:

```
Origi\\\"nal
Origi\"nal
```

Can someone please suggest a way forward?

Comment: your sample strimgs are the same, so why do they have diffrent outcomes? besides theses are strings so you can use replace, if there are fixed rules

Comment: @nbk The strings were not the same in the source, but StackOverflow uses \ for escaping, so they looked the same in the output.

Comment: @nbk I just gave a sample, technically I want Redshift to write dynamic strings as json

Comment: Redshift hasn't git a lot of json functions and noe of them apply here, but as i said already they are only string, so replace " with /" and /" with ///"